# Probability of getting a seat in the train car

Tags: probability, self-study, binomial-distribution, independence

A train has got five train cars, each one with N seats. There are 150 passengers who randomly choose one of the cars. What is the probability that everyone will get a seat?

I think that what is asking me is  "what is the probability that each wagon is chosen by no more than N passengers"?

The probability of having $n<N$ people in *a* wagon is given by
$$p_N=\sum\limits_{n=0}^N \binom{150}{n}0.2^n 0.8^{150-n}$$.

I thought of the answer being $p_N^5$.. but I think that the events

- wagon a is chosen by no more than N passengers
- wagon b is chosen by no more than N passengers
- wagon c is chosen by no more than N passengers
- wagon d is chosen by no more than N passengers
- wagon e is chosen by no more than N passengers

are far from being independent... So what could I do?
Thanks a lot

Comment: What makes you think that these events are not independent?

Comment: @RubenvanBergen well I think that if 150 passengers choose wagon a then the probability of the other 4 events in the list is 0.. I mean, more than N passengers in a specific wagon reduce the probabilities of the other events.. isn't it?